# Fastest way to pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
                 df1
    date_start   date_end   ID
```

and

```
                 df2
    ID   timestamp   quantity
```

and want to get for each tuple (in df1) (date_start, date_end, ID) the sum of the quantity relative to that ID in the corresponding period [date_start, date_end] ( in df2) .

How could I proceed provided I have tens of thousands of rows and there are many repetitions in df1?

I tried `df1.drop_duplicates().apply(lambda x: df2[(df2['timestamp'] >= x['date_start']) & (df2['timestamp'] <= x['date_end']) & (df2['ID'] == x['ID'])]['quantity'].sum())`

but it takes too much time !

Thanks

Comment: generally the answer to *faster way to pandas apply* is to not use apply. In this case, something like a `df1.merge(df2, on='ID')` and query the dates would work.